Ошибка при отправке сообщения aiogram
Проблема в том что при записи юзернейма записывается юзернейм бота а не пользователя, как это исправить?
@router.message()
async def start(call: CallbackQuery):
   global username
   username = call.message.from_user.username
     
   @router.message()
   async def start(message : Message, bot : Bot):
       global username 
       bot.send_message(f'Username: {username}')


Бери from_user у CallbackQuery:
callback_query.from_user.username

Обрати внимание, что у тебя нет фильтров на хендлерах, и это может привести к тому, что будет отрабатывать только первый зарегистрированный.
Также советую избавиться от глобальных переменных.

На счёт фильтров, они есть просто я не написал их, что касается глобальных переменных, я использую эти юзеры в разных хенлдерах по этому отказываются от них я не могу, я стараюсь сокращать их по минимуму

Глобальные переменные - лучше либо data state использовать, либо тянуть каждый раз из callback_query/message, но это все зависит от конкретного кейса и задачи, о которых сведений мало.
Отправка сообщения - так как это aiogram, то отправка сообщения должна идти с await.
Удачки
